# How to draw non-square tick marks

Tags: java, android, wear-os

In the below picture, I'm trying to figure out how to draw the tick marks seen on the watch face. I know how to draw lines, but I'm unsure how to draw "tapered" lines like the picture. How can I accomplish this for Android Wear? I think I need to create a `Path`, but I don't know how to generate the `Path` coordinates.

[image: ticks]

Comment: What if you use vector or other png?

Comment: I'd rather not if possible. No reason other than I don't want to have to deal with loading bitmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a `Path` you need to do something like this:

```
Path path = new Path();

// Start at the top left corner
path.moveTo(screenCenterX - halfMarkerTopWidth, topMargin);

// Draw a line to the top right corner
path.lineTo(screenCenterX + halfMarkerTopWidth, topMargin);

// Draw a line to the bottom right corner
path.lineTo(screenCenterX + halfMarkerBottomWidth, topMargin + markerHeight);

// Draw a line to the bottom left corner
path.lineTo(screenCenterX - halfMarkerBottomWidth, topMargin + markerHeight);

// Close the Path (will automatically draw a line back to the top left corner)
path.close();
```

Then draw your path 12 times and just rotate the canvas 30 degrees between each time you draw it.

```
canvas.save();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    canvas.rotate(30, screenCenterX, screenCenterY);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Your solution works--but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to draw it 12 times now. Calling `canvas.rotate(30)` doesn't yield the expected result.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could point one of these Paths to the current hour?

Comment: Added some code for drawing it. Not sure what you mean with "point one of these Paths to the current hour" means? If it is the highlight effect seen in the screenshot in your question all you have to do is change the color of your Paint when drawing the one that corresponds to the current hour. If you only want on that's pointing at the current hour simply calculate the angle of that hour, e.g. 6 o'clock would be 180 degrees, and rotate the canvas once using that value.